# In vim is there a command for inline replacing of a line?

Tags: vim

I would like to navigate to a line and start typing immediately . This should replace the contents of the existing line. It is basically *replacing a line* command but inline similar to what we can achieve through Change Inline word<kbd>c+i+w</kbd>. How can I do that without first going to the line and then pressing  <kbd>dd</kbd> and then going to *insert* mode and typing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`S` should do what you want. It deletes the line and places you in insert mode.

`S` is a synonym for `cc`

From `:h cc`

```
                                                        cc
["x]cc                  Delete [count] lines [into register x] and start
                        insert linewise.  If 'autoindent' is on, preserve
                        the indent of the first line.
```

From `:h S`

```
                                                        S
["x]S                   Delete [count] lines [into register x] and start
                        insert.  Synonym for "cc" linewise.
```

Comment: @FDinoff What does the `["x]` mean?

Comment: @Geek the `["x]` is an optional part of the command that allows you to put the deleted part into register x. You can replace x with any other letter to put the deleted part into that register. If you do not specify a register it gets placed in the default one.